# Python3 Gerrit Requests Get Reponse Json starts with )]}

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, gerrit

I am making a REST call to a gerrit server. Pretty straight forward expect I don't understand the response Looking at network traffic from Chrome, Chrome gets the same response. So I am guessing I simply don't understand how to parse the response.  Here is my code and some of the response:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

url = 'https://my.gerrit.server.com/changes/?n=1&q=owner=me'

headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'charset' : 'UTF-8'}
response = requests.get(url, verify=False, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('usernmae', 'password'), headers=headers)
```

If we print response.text, we get this:

```
')]}\'\n[\n  {\n    "id": "some_id, ... ,\n    "requirements": []\n  }\n]\n'
```

It all looks like valid JSON except the beginning **)]}**.

How do I parse this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to strip prefix characters before passing this value to JSON parser.

```py
s[4:] if s.startswith(')]}\'') else s
```

```py
>>> s = ')]}\'\n[\n  {\n    "id": "some_id",\n    "requirements": []\n  }\n]\n'
>>> json.loads(s[4:] if s.startswith(')]}\'') else s)
[{'id': 'some_id', 'requirements': []}]
```

From Gerrit documentation at https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#output

> To prevent against Cross Site Script Inclusion (XSSI) attacks, the JSON response body starts with a magic prefix line that must be stripped before feeding the rest of the response body to a JSON parser:
>
> ```
>   )]}'
>   [ ... valid JSON ... ]
> ```